# How to add input tag to the last row of ui grid on button click

Tags: angularjs, ui-grid

I am having a situation where I want to add input box at the end of the table. Is it possible to do this in **ui-grid**. I know **rowTemplate**, but it applies to whole column. I want to apply only to the last row of the table.

Comment: Hi .. i don't know very well kendo ui for angular..but i think you can try to do somthing like check when row is the $last in the data-ng-repeat and if is it ..insert your input

Comment: Can you share a code snippet / Plunker to support your question ?